# How do I send an email for every error that occurs in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js, error-handling, express

Let's say my node.js app is running.  If there is an error (I mean ALL errors. Not just the web error.  If it goes to Err out, it counts) , how can I call a function to send an email to me?

Basically, before I want it to write to err.out, I want an email sent to me.

I'm using node.js and express.

Edit: I know how to send an email.  The question I want to know is how to **intercept the error**.
You know how when there's an error, it logs to **out.log**?   Well, right now, I'm tail -f out.log, monitoring for errors.  I can't sit at home all day doing this. I want errors emailed  to me anytime it pops up in out.log.

I want ***all*** errors emailed to me. (Not just Express errors).  If it's logged, I want that error emailed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could replace nodes global console.error() function with one implementation sending emails:

```
console.error = function(msg) {
  // send email
  // ...

  // additionaly log
  process.stderr.write(msg);
};
```

Then ***every call in every library*** made to console.error() would call your specific implementation send out mails ;)

Comment: Where do I put this?   in my app.js ? (I'm using Node.js Express)

Comment: Even other stuff (mongoose, redis) will go through this? (if i put it in app.js??)

Comment: You can put anywhere (but as early as possible is best), and yes EVERY call to console.error() in ANY library will then call your special console.error() function.

Comment: Why not just overwrite `Error` with a custom constructor

Comment: I added your solution to my Node+Express App. But it doesn't execute the custom actions like it is expected to do but still logging error in the terminal. I followed your instructions but still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since all log entries are stored in a limited number of log files, in stead of trying to intercept all possible error events, why not just set up a file change monitor and have the new lines mailed to you? That way you can also schedule intervals with summary log entries of the last hour/day/... which will be a lot easier to go through, compared to opening separate mails.