# Node js error logs in terminal will trigger to send me an email

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I am trying to create a way to send me an email each time my node application encounters any kind of error so that when in production mode I can get notified to investigate and create a solution for that error. So basically, I needed the error log shown in the terminal sent to my email.

The problem is that I couldn't find the relatable reference. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204474/how-do-i-send-an-email-for-every-error-that-occurs-in-node-js) but it just executes whenever you call console.error and doesn't it dynamically executes in any errors like reference error.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
    //send email with info about e
    process.exit(1);
});
```

or if you are using pm2

```
var ipm2 = require('pm2-interface')();

ipm2.on('ready', function() { 
    ipm2.bus.on('process:exception', function(data){
    //send email with info about data
  });
});
```